# How to deal with indeterminate form in Python

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

At some point in my python script, I require to make the calculation: `1*(-inf + 6.28318530718j).` I understand why this will return `-inf + nan*j` since the imaginary component of `1` is obviously `0`, but I would like the multiplication to have the return value of `-inf + 6.28318530718j` as would be expected. I also want whatever solution to be robust to any of these kinds of multiplications. Any ideas?

Edit:

A Complex multiplication like `x*y` where `x = (a+ib)` and `y = (c+id)` I assume is handled like `(x.real*y.real-x.imag*y.imag)+1j*(x.real*y.imag+x.imag*y.real)` in python as this is what the multiplication comes down to mathematically. Now if say `x=1.0` and `y=-inf+1.0j` then the result will contain `nan`'s as `inf*0` will be undefined. I want a way for python to interpret `*` so that the return value to this example will be `-inf+1.0j`. It seems unnecessary to have to define my own multiplication operator (via say a function `cmultiply(x,y)`) such that I get the desired result.

Comment: `1*(-inf + 6.28318530718j)` doesn't return anything for me. I get a `NameError`

Comment: Try doing `np.log(0)` what does that return?

Comment: Perhaps what I should be doing is avoiding `inf` and having the possibility of overflow errors through an exception instead. But I'm not sure how to do this... Python will return `inf` if I use `np.log(0)`.

Comment: For potential answerers that don't have numpy, you can replicate the OP's problem with `1*(float("-inf") + 6.2j)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `np.log(0)`, I get a warning like:

```
>>> 1*(np.log(0) + 6.28318530718j)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cdouble_scalars
(-inf+nan*j)
```

I would advise against trying to "work with" `inf` and `nan`. You can change the behaviour of numpy using [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

```
>>> np.seterr(divide='raise')
{'over': 'warn', 'divide': 'raise', 'invalid': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}
>>> 1*(np.log(0) + 6.28318530718j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in log
```

Now you can catch the `FloatingPointError` exception and deal with it in some useful way.

Note that the `nan` part of original answer is actually a side effect of the `inf`. If you do:

```
>>> 1*(2 + 6.28318530718j)
(2+6.28318530718j)
```

If one part of the multiplication has no complex component, it doesn't create a `nan` in the other side.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is I want to be able to have `np.log(0)` return something in the sense that `np.exp(np.log(0))` will return `0`. Alternatively i guess `np.log(0)` returning a very small number is also permissible. Matlab seems to have this figured out. I understand that the `nan` was created by the `inf`. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. `np.exp(np.log(x)) == x` by definition. I think that you need to deal with this on a case by case basis and decide what to do. Perhaps you could edit your question to provide some more concrete examples.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the C99 standard (Annex G) on complex number arithmetic recognizes only a single complex infinity (think: Riemann sphere). `(inf, nan)` is one representation for it, and `(-inf, 6j)`  is another, equivalent representation.